# How to override js file in lib folder for admin theme?

Tags: javascript, overrides, magento-2.1.9

I need to override **js** located in `lib/web/mage/backend` in `Magento/backend`theme.

***Basically i should get modified js in static content for admin theme.***

Answer (score -1):

you should place the files in

```
app/design/frontend/YOURVENDOR/YOURTHEME/web/mage/backend/
```